# Extract the 3D stereo images from a 3D video in MV-HEVC format

Tags: ios, objective-c, 3d, avfoundation

I would like extract the both 3D stereo images (left/right) from a 3D spatial video in MV-HEVC format. I use code, iOS, Objective-C.

Here is my code to read a 2D video:

```objc
NSURL *inputVideoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:inputVideoPath]; 
AVURLAsset *inputAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputVideoURL options:nil]; AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:inputAsset]; 

for (int i=1;i<=maxx;i++) { 
    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(i, (int32_t)frameRate);  
    CGImageRef imageRef = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&error]; 
    UIImage *image=nil; 
    image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
}
```

Comment: FYI - the Apple project at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_reading_and_writing/reading_multiview_3d_video_files?language=objc does have what you need. The important file is StereoViewModel.swift. It's trivial to make that work for iOS. Change `NSImage` to `UIImage` and `NSSize` to `CGSize`. Then of course you need to convert to Objective-C. Focus on the APIs used, not the language. Focus on just the parts that extract each pair of images for each frame. All of the AVFoundation and VideoToolBox APIs are there in both languages.